# Windows 7 style live previews

Tags: window-manager, windows-7

Is it possible to get windows 7 style live previews of what a window is doing, when it is hovered over?

for instance, when i hover over a video player on windows 7, i can see the video playing in the preview.

Something that works on the gnome panel would be good, but even better would be a docky or awn implementation?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried dockbarx? here are some instructions.
http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DockbarX?content=101604
[image]

[image]

Comment: window 7 themes are available with the extra pack i believe the theme is called tonky bar.

Comment: not so much after the appearance, just the functionality

Comment: I think that Dockbarx doesn't show live preview on minimized windows, just like Compiz plugin.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/compiz-092-released-with-minimized-live.html) is interesting to you.

Answer (score 6):

Compiz (the default effects engine that can be turned on) has had a Window Previews plugin since well-before Windows 7 was around. It just provides a preview for a window. It doesn't stack them and it only works for windows that aren't minimised (although I think there are some hacks to get around that).

To enable it, turn on compiz:

1. Right click the desktop
2. Click Change Desktop Background
3. Select the Visual Effects tab
4. Use Normal or Extra

Extra *may* turn this on by default (I don't want to test it as I like my current compiz settings). Test it by hovering over a running program.

If it doesn't you want the CompizConfig Settings Manager (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`). Once installed, load it from the System -> Preferences menu.

Use the filter box to search for "preview" and turn the option on by checking the checkbox. You'll end up with something like this:

[image: Window Previews]

Comment: It doesn't show live previews when a Window is minimized though. Upstream problem I know but nevertheless still a problem.

Comment: not working with minimized windows could be a show stopper, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue in the latest Compiz as it can continue to render things offscreen when they're minimised. That could have a performance hit but it does mean previews should continue to work.

Answer (score 2):

The KDE desktop environment has this effect. If you like KDE, you can still install and use most Gnome applications without any ill effect. (I personally prefer Gnome though).

Comment: Unfortunately im a gnome man through and through, i never seemed to get on with kde, thanks for the suggest though.